# Microsoft Forms Preview API

Tags: c#, forms, office365

Microsoft Office 365 Education has a new product called Microsoft Forms.

forms.office.com

This is similar to Google forms, allowing users to create forms which collect data which is exportable via Excel.

Is there an API to access a given reports data ?

Currently it lacks the ability to email when responses are received and the export appears to be web only.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Forms doesn't support the extensions through developer APIs. Please refer to the features it doesn't support:

*Microsoft Forms Preview doesn’t allow embedding images or videos, themes, question branching, co-authoring of forms, and **extensions through developer APIs**. Microsoft Forms Preview will evolve over time and additional functionality will be added based on customer feedback*.

If there is any of feature you required that you can submit the feedback . You can click More Options (...) in the upper right corner of the Microsoft Forms Preview window and then click Feedback.